# Annoying javascript timezone adjustment issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, iso8601

I have set up a JSON endpoint that returns the current time from server. For example:

```
{
  "myservertime": "2011-10-02T23:00+02:00"
}
```

So this is the CET summer time right now.

Now, I also have a jQuery code that parses that very well.

```
$.sysTime = function(success) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/jsontimepath/',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function(json){
                    sysDateTime = new Date(Date.parse(json.myservertime));
                    console.log('The system time now is: ' + sysDateTime)
                }
            });

            return sysDateTime;
        };
```

The problem is that when I check the console, it still shows wrong time... It is still affected by the timezone of my computer... For example, for a user in Hong Kong, the time quoted above would result:

Mon Oct 03 2011 05:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)

I do give it a valid ISO8601 time string and it just adjusts it. The actual time that is returned is correct (in that timezone)... But why does it adjust it like that??? I want it to return CET time not the local time...

Comment: Why not simply show it as a string then, instead of parsing it?

Comment: Because, I am the date to initiate another AJAX query and fetch some events based on that server date. All the events are CEST (or CET) and if a visitor is in different timezone and in that timezone there's new day, then all the results get messed up...

Answer (score 15):

Everything is fine, try this:

```
new Date(Date.parse("2011-10-02T23:00+02:00")).getUTCHours()  //21
```

The date is parsed correctly (taking the timezone into account as expected). However when you simply print `Date.toString()` it shows the date in current browser timezone (one of the sins of Java `Date` object shamelessly copied to JavaScript...)

If you stick to `getUTC*()` family of methods you will get correct values (like in example above). The ordinary `get*()` methods are always affected by browser timezone (and not the timezone from the date you parsed, which is lost), hence often useless.

Another example: the *2011-10-03 02:00+03:00* is actually 23:00 on 2nd of October. But when you parse it (my current browser time zone is +0200 (CEST)):

```
new Date(Date.parse("2011-10-03T02:00+03:00"))  //Oct 03 01:00:00 GMT+0200
```

However current day of month in UTC is:

```
new Date(Date.parse("2011-10-03T02:00+03:00")).getUTCDate()  //2 (2nd of Oct)
```

Comment: And if you need to retain the original time zone offset from the JSON data, you will need to parse that portion of it yourself and retain it separately.

Comment: No, don't do that. The only format specified in ECMA-262 is ISO 8601 with UTC as the timezone, there is no requirement to parse time zone information and many browsers in use will not do so. The only reliable way to parse date strings it to do it yourself (or use a suitable library), do not use *Date.parse* (or the Date constructor, which just calls *Date.parse*).