# Converting Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

My AJAX call returns the datetime value as this

`/Date(1320120000000-0400)/`

How do I convert it to a readable format (e.g. 11/31/2011) using Javascript?

Comment: It would be nice if you told us the original date string of the  `1320120000000-0400` timestamp. The very basic: `(new Date(1320120000000)).toString()`.

Comment: Also, what kind of server are you getting this date from?

Comment: this is passed from an  Oracle database (date field) via web service(.net)

Answer (score 1):

This is the number of milliseconds since epoch:

```
new Date(1320120000000) //Tue Nov 01 2011 05:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

However, `-0400` seems to be a GMT offset which you also have to apply. I guess it has a format of `HHMM`, so in this case you have to subtract 4:00 hours from given value:

```
new Date(1320120000000 - 4 * 3600 * 1000)  //Tue Nov 01 2011 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Finally note that the `Date.toString()` method shown in comments uses browser time zone (CET in my case, see: [Annoying javascript timezone adjustment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629286)). You should use `getUTC*()` methods on `Date` to get accurate results not affected by browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime("1320120000000");
```

This should work

You can now format it to a string using, getDay, getMonth,getFullYear methods.

[Read More here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `toDateString` will return just the date portion formatted in a human readable form in American English ("Mon Oct 31 2011").

If you specifically need "11/31/2011", then build a custom string using `getMonth`, `getDate`, and `getFullYear`.

```
var date = new Date(1320120000000-0400);
var formatted = date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
```

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date