# How can I convert a date to GMT?

Tags: javascript

How to convert date of different timezones to GMT 0? Let say I have dates like this

```
Fri Jan 20 2012 11:51:36 GMT-0500
Fri Jan 20 2012 11:51:36 GMT-0300
Fri Jan 20 2012 11:51:36 GMT+0500
```

to

```
Fri Jan 20 2012 06:51:36 GMT
Fri Jan 20 2012 08:51:36 GMT
Fri Jan 20 2012 16:51:36 GMT
```

these are dates I am getting via `new Date().toString()` on different timezones. Is there any js method to detect timezone and convert accordingly?

EDIT: The second three dates are not the GMT converted times of the first three. For example, `Fri Jan 20 2012 11:51:36 GMT-0500` in GMT is `Fri Jan 20 2012 16:51:36 GMT` not `Fri Jan 20 2012 06:51:36 GMT`. GMT-0500 is behind GMT, not ahead, so you have to add the offset to get GMT, not subtract it.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[Matt Johnson-Pint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson-pint)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26454317/334274) is much better than this one was.

```js
console.log(new Date("Fri Jan 20 2012 11:51:36 GMT-0500").toUTCString())
```

Comment: Not correct. getTimezoneOffset is in minutes, and you use 3.6M seconds. it should be 60K seconds instead. protip, never use big numbers, new Date(date3.getTime() + (date3.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)); Prefer instead meaningful multiplications (even though they're overhead), or better, variables like var seconds=1000;var minutes=60*seconds;

Comment: @Morg The last comment explained that it needed to be 3.6M seconds... I forget why. If you check the edits, I had originally put 60K seconds. Can you confirm that was right before I revert?

Comment: I have no idea why someone would want that, I however know that your formula cannot work if you treat a value in minutes like a value in seconds. Sure thing is, copy pasting your code will result in epic fail, so I guess it's better to return it to something that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong.  `getTimezoneOffset` returns an offset based on the date it is called on, and the time zone of the computer the code is running on.  It does *not* supply the offset passed in when constructing a date from a string.   Also - Adding the offset to the date timestamp as shown here is just going to shift the moment in time you're working with.  It will *still* return string results based on the time zone of the local computer - using that time zone's daylight saving time rules.

Comment: UTC and GMT are not the same!

Comment: @AFriend But they share the same time.

Answer (score 49):

You can simply use the `toUTCString`  (or `toISOString`) methods of the date object.

Example:

```
new Date("Fri Jan 20 2012 11:51:36 GMT-0500").toUTCString()

// Output:  "Fri, 20 Jan 2012 16:51:36 GMT"
```

If you prefer better control of the output format, consider using a library such as [date-fns](https://date-fns.org) or [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Also, in your question, you've actually converted the time incorrectly.  When an offset is shown in a timestamp string, it means that the date and time values in the string have *already* been adjusted from UTC by that value.   To convert back to UTC, invert the sign before applying the offset.

```
11:51:36 -0300  ==  14:51:36Z
```

Comment: This is definitely a better answer than mine.

Comment: But the problem with this solution is that if I need to do some manipulation with date it won't work such as getMonth and getDate

Comment: @BlackMamba - that is a separate issue than the one asked in the question.  Also, easily addressable as there are UTC versions of those functions.

Comment: I agree but I also found the solution great but later on found that it's hard to use it for further calculation

Comment: This allowed me to compare dates as well, nice.

Comment: `toGMTString()` is deprecated to `toUTCString()`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString

Comment: @Jivings—you can edit your answer to include the correct answer.

Answer (score 44):

Although it looks logical, the accepted answer is incorrect because JavaScript dates don't work like that.

It's super important to note here that the numerical value of a date (i.e., `new Date()-0` or `Date.now()`) in JavaScript is always measured as *millseconds since the epoch* which is a **timezone-free quantity based on a precise exact instant in the history of the universe**. You do not need to add or subtract anything to the numerical value returned from `Date()` to convert the numerical value into a timezone, because the numerical value **has no timezone**. If it did have a timezone, everything else in JavaScript dates wouldn't work.

Timezones, leap years, leap seconds, and all of the other endlessly complicated adjustments to our local times and dates, are based on this consistent and unambiguous numerical value, not the other way around.

Here are examples of how the numerical value of a date (provided to the date constructor) is independent of timezone:

In Central Standard Time:

```
new Date(0);
// Wed Dec 31 1969 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

In Anchorage, Alaska:

```
new Date(0);
// Wed Dec 31 1969 15:00:00 GMT-0900 (AHST)
```

In Paris, France:

```
new Date(0);
// Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

It is critical to observe that in ALL cases, based on the timezone-free epoch offset of zero milliseconds, the resulting time is identical. 1 am in Paris, France is the exact same moment as 3 pm the day before in Anchorage, Alaska, which is the exact same moment as 6 pm in Chicago, Illinois.

For this reason, the accepted answer on this page is incorrect. Observe:

```
// Create a date.
   date = new Date();
// Fri Jan 27 2017 18:16:35 GMT-0600 (CST)


// Observe the numerical value of the date.
   date.valueOf();
// 1485562595732
// n.b. this value has no timezone and does not need one!!


// Observe the incorrectly "corrected" numerical date value.
   date.valueOf() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
// 1485584195732


// Try out the incorrectly "converted" date string.
   new Date(date.valueOf() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
// Sat Jan 28 2017 00:16:35 GMT-0600 (CST)

/* Not the correct result even within the same script!!!! */
```

If you have a date string in another timezone, *no conversion to the resulting object created by `new Date("date string")` is needed*. Why? JavaScript's numerical value of that date will be the same regardless of its timezone. JavaScript automatically goes through amazingly complicated procedures to extract the original number of milliseconds since the epoch, no matter what the original timezone was.

The bottom line is that plugging a textual date string `x` into the `new Date(x)` constructor will automatically convert from the original timezone, whatever that might be, into the timezone-free epoch milliseconds representation of time which is the same regardless of any timezone. In your actual application, you can choose to *display* the date in any timezone that you want, but do NOT add/subtract to the numerical value of the date in order to do so. All the conversion already happened at the instant the date object was created. The timezone isn't even there anymore, because the date object is instantiated using a precisely-defined and timezone-free sense of time.

The timezone only begins to exist again when the user of your application is considered. The user does have a timezone, so you simply *display* that timezone to the user. But this also happens *automatically*.

Let's consider a couple of the dates in your original question:

```
   date1 = new Date("Fri Jan 20 2012 11:51:36 GMT-0300");
// Fri Jan 20 2012 08:51:36 GMT-0600 (CST)


   date2 = new Date("Fri Jan 20 2012 11:51:36 GMT-0300")
// Fri Jan 20 2012 08:51:36 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

The console already knows my timezone, and so it has *automatically* shown me what those times mean to me.

And if you want to know the time in GMT/UTC representation, also no conversion is needed! You don't change the time at all. You simply display the UTC string of the time:

```
    date1.toUTCString();
// "Fri, 20 Jan 2012 14:51:36 GMT"
```

Code that is written to convert timezones numerically using the numerical value of a JavaScript date is almost guaranteed to fail. Timezones are way too complicated, and that's why JavaScript was designed so that you didn't need to.

Comment: While you are correct, note that the Date constructor will assume a timezone if not given. If I do `new Date("9/9/19")` it will use the timezone of the client. So, if you want to interpret the date as if it were being given in GMT, you'll need to remove the timezone offset, as stated in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Azmisov 'you'll need to remove the timezone offset, as stated in the accepted answer' -- if you use the method I suggest, then this is not needed even in the case you mention. The solution I suggest is sufficient. Try the following in the JavaScript console: `x = new Date('Fri Jan 20 2012 11:51:36 GMT-0500'); x.toUTCString()` and you will end up with `"Fri, 20 Jan 2012 16:51:36 GMT"` as desired by the original poster. Also, even without the time zone, the user's time zone is assumed (just as you say) but the conversion is still done correctly by `toUTCString()`.

Comment: Yeah, I think that works because you give a timezone in the constructor `GMT-0500`. Seems it does not work when there is no timezone given.

Comment: For example: `+(new Date("9/9/19")) != +(new Date("9/9/19 GMT-000"))`

Comment: @Azmisov. Did you even try? As I mentioned, even without the time zone, the user's time zone is assumed, but the conversion is still absolutely correct. Are you expecting something different if the timezone is not specified? For example, if my computer is in CDT, then: `x = new Date('9/20/2017');`
*Wed Sep 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)*
`x.toUTCString()`
*"Wed, 20 Sep 2017 05:00:00 GMT"* Everything works perfectly. Bottom line: a programmer does not "need" to remove the time zone offset with magical math. The system does it for you. You should *not* attempt to do it on your own.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood my comments. Your output is `Wed, 20 Sep 2017 05:00:00 GMT`. If you wanted `9/20/2017` interpreted as if it were given in GMT timezone, the correct output should be `Wed, 20 Sep 2017 00:00:00 GMT`. So you'd have to remove the timezone offset in that case. I'm not saying that's what the OP wanted; my comment was just an aside for anyone needing to do this. I'm not criticizing your answer or anything.

Comment: Thank you both @Joseph_Myers and @Azmisov. This answered my exact question. I have a date `2022-02-22 22:22:22` that I know to be in GMT-0 (no timezone offset) but I wasn't sure sure the best way to create the date object based on THAT timezone until your answer and comments. Just append `GMT-0` (`new Date('2022-02-22 22:22:22 GMT-0`))

Answer (score 23):

Simply use [`Date.getUTC*()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) family of methods. On my computer (CET, UTC+01:00):

```
new Date().toString()
//Fri Jan 20 2012 18:05:16 GMT+0100 (CET)

new Date().getHours()
//18

new Date().getUTCHours()
//17
```

Notice that `getUTCHours()` returns correct hour in UTC.

#### See also:

- [Annoying javascript timezone adjustment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629286)

Answer (score 4):

I was just working on this, I may be a bit late, 
but I did a workaround. 
Here are steps: 
 - Get current time from whatever timezone the app is fired.-
 - Get time zone offset of that zone from gmt 0. then add your timezone value in 
   miliseconds.
 You will get the date in your time zone. I added some extra code to remove anything after the actual time.

```
getCurrentDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    var newDate = new Date(8 * 60 * 60000 + date.valueOf() + 
                           (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
    var ampm = newDate.getHours() < 12 ? ' AM' : ' PM';
    var strDate = newDate + '';
    return (strDate).substring(0, strDate.indexOf(' GMT')) + ampm
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for my situation. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the accepted answer and the second highest scoring answer both are not perfect according to the comment so I mixed both to get something perfect:

```js
var date = new Date(); //Current timestamp
date = date.toGMTString(); 
//Based on the time zone where the date was created
console.log(date);

/*based on the comment getTimezoneOffset returns an offset based 
on the date it is called on, and the time zone of the computer the code is
 running on. It does not supply the offset passed in when constructing a 
date from a string. */

date = new Date(date); //will convert to present timestamp offset
date = new Date(date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)); 
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am trying with the below. This seems to be working fine. Are there any limitations to this approach? Please confirm.

```
var now=new Date();                         // Sun Apr 02 2017 2:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)
var gmtRe = /GMT([\-\+]?\d{4})/;
var tz = gmtRe.exec(now)[1];               // +1000
var hour=tz/100;                           // 10
var min=tz%100;                            // 0
now.setHours(now.getHours()-hour);
now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes()-min);      // Sat Apr 01 2017 16:00:00 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching for an hour or two, I've found a simple solution below.

```
const date = new Date(`${date from client} GMT`);
```

> inside double ticks, there is a date from client side plust GMT.

Answer (score 0):

GMTDate = new Date().toGMTString();

Comment: `toGMTString()` is deprecated to `toUTCString()`, as the documentation shows https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString

Answer (score 0):

**Example date string**

```
var dateString = '2024-02-19T15:30:00';
```

**Create a Date object from the date string**

```
var date = new Date(dateString);
```

**Convert the date to GMT string**

```
var gmtDateString = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'GMT'});

console.log("Date in GMT:", gmtDateString);
```