# How do I make this countdown the same timezone for everyone?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make this countdown the same timezone for everyone?
http://jsfiddle.net/3LnFm/

I need UTC timezone

Here is the JS-

```
var end = new Date('27 Dec 2013 15:29:00'); // set expiry date and time..

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour *24
var timer;

function showRemaining()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0 ) {

       clearInterval( timer );

       return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor( (distance % _day ) / _hour );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (distance % _hour) / _minute );
    var seconds = Math.floor( (distance % _minute) / _second );

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Days: ' + days + '<br />';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += 'Hours: ' + hours+ '<br />';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += 'Minutes: ' + minutes+ '<br />';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += 'Seconds: ' + seconds+ '<br />';
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945029/converting-date-to-gmt-0

Answer (score 0):

use `date_default_timezone_set("UTC");`