# Javascript Date(): How to convert the local date to GMT

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm sending the server time object with zero date, the sent date is:
Thu Jan 01 1970 01:02:01 GMT+0200
How can I convert it to GMT+0000? I need to tell the server about some task duration, so I want it to be just 01:02:01 as a duration. But the sent date is local and the server understands it as 03:02:01! How can I zero the GMT index?

Thanks

Comment: You can use UTC to avoid timezone difference, but I will prefer to send and operate a number of seconds

Comment: Maybe this can help you. 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945029/converting-date-to-gmt-0][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945029/converting-date-to-gmt-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the GMT time out of a JavaScript Date object is simple enough -

> Date.prototype.toUTCString()
>   The toUTCString() method converts a date to a string, using the UTC time zone.

For example:

```
var test = new Date('Thu Jan 01 1970 01:02:01 GMT+0200').toUTCString();
console.log(test);
```

Note that this correctly outputs `Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:02:01 GMT`, which although it not what you are looking for, is converting the provided Date to GMT.

To get what you want out of your input, a regular expression is useful. Caveats:

- assumes duration will never be more than 23 hours, 59 minutes, and 59 seconds. If it is **this will break**.

```js
var test = 'Thu Jan 01 1970 01:02:01 GMT+0200';
var durationMatcher = /\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/; 
console.log(test.match(durationMatcher));
```

If you can, consider working in some values that works for you with one number - number of milliseconds for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertToGmt(pdate)
{
var newDate = new Date(pdate);
    return (newDate.getUTCHours()<10?"0"+newDate.getUTCHours():newDate.getUTCHours())+":"+(newDate.getUTCMinutes()<10?"0"+newDate.getUTCMinutes():newDate.getUTCMinutes())+":"+(newDate.getUTCSeconds()<10?"0"+newDate.getUTCSeconds():newDate.getUTCSeconds());
}
```

Now use this `function` and call it by passing you date.

Notice that `getUTCHours()` returns correct hour in UTC.

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/um8syzke/1/)**