# Firefox new Date() from string constructs time in local time zone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I am trying to create a date object from a string. 
I get date in ISO format except milliseconds part like "2012-01-30T16:23:12"

Results differ when I run following code in  IE, Chrome and Firefox
([Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harsha/9ybtN/))

```
currentDate = "2012-01-30T16:23:12";
var date = new Date(currentDate);
alert(date);
```

IE and Chrome considers the string as UTC but firefox considers in local time zone.

Is there any generic way to get around it except for checking user agent everywhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Annoying javascript timezone adjustment issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629286/annoying-javascript-timezone-adjustment-issue)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try appending the zero timezone offset `+00:00` for UTC:

```
currentDate = "2012-01-30T16:23:12+00:00";
```

Does that help? (Sorry I can't test it without actually changing my timezone.)

Comment: Thanks. It works with "+00:00".That way all three browsers yield same epoch value. http://jsfiddle.net/harsha/9ybtN/2/

Comment: Sorry, yes it needs the colon

Answer (score 3):

Hm, possible workaround is to parse string and use methods.

```
setUTCDate()    
setUTCFullYear()
setUTCHours()
```

Probably, there is better solution

Comment: +1, this is not a workaround but the *correct way*, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629286

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the input will be correctly parsed if in the present format. The Date.parse() routine is only required to parse strings in a particular format—parsing other formats is implementation-dependent. If you dare to rely on implementations satisfying the requirement, add data to conform to the specific format:

```
new Date(currentDate + '.000Z')
```

Alternatively, use a library that can parse data in the current format, e.g. jQuery or Globalize.js.

Similar considerations apply to writing dates. There is no guarantee of the output format if you use `Date.toString()`, either explicitly or as in `alert(date)`. Even within a single computer, different browsers will use different localized formats.