# given an offset how can i convert the current time to UTC time in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
a = new Date();
Sun Apr 08 2012 16:58:03 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Is there any way i can get the current UTC time?
I thought of getting an offset doing maths:

```
b = a.getTimezoneOffset()
-330
```

then subtract, get the value:

```
c = a - b
1333884483552
```

but again getting `c` as `a` to look is difficult. So the question:
**How can i get the current UTC time, in javascript?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin called **jstimezonedetect** which you can use to detect the timezone. You can find it [here](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect)

Or use date's UTC methods like

```
var now = new Date(); 
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/XzL26/)

> **Outputs**
>
> Date {Sun Apr 08 2012 18:31:50 GMT+0545 (Nepal Standard Time)}
>
> Date {Sun Apr 08 2012 12:46:50 GMT+0545 (Nepal Standard Time)}

Comment: This is **not** a correct solution, although it looks like one... My local time is now `14:45:34 GMT+0200 (CEST)`, your code returns `12:45:34 GMT+0200 (CEST)`. It didn't return my current time in UTC. Instead it returns `Date` 2 hours in the past, still in my local time zone `GMT+0200 (CEST)`.

Comment: No, I am not ;-). And your demo support me. `Date` represents point in time, irrespective to time zone. Your code should return `12:46:50 GMT+0000` for `18:31:50 GMT+0545` - these represent **the same point in time**. However your code returns two different points in time, both in `GMT+0545`. See: http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php - it is about Java, but `Date` in JS is 1:1 to `Date` in Java. In other words - two same dates in different time zones should have the same number of millis since epoch (they represent same point in time). Try calling `+now` and `+now_utc` on your code...

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz, Ok, I am confused

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `Date` object in JavaScript is timezone-independent. It only stores the number of milliseconds since epoch. Furthermore it **always** uses browser time zone for `toString()` and `get*()` methods. You cannot create `Date` instance in a different time zone.

Thus simply use `getUTC*()` family of methods:

```
new Date().getUTCHours()
new Date().getUTCMinutes()
//...
```

to obtain time in UTC.

Last but not least - your code is broken. `a` variable represents `Date` and is casted to milliseconds here: `c = a - b`. However `b` is equal to `a.getTimezoneOffset()`. The time zone offset is in *minutes*. You are subtracting minutes from milliseconds...

## See also

- [Annoying javascript timezone adjustment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629286)

Comment: please mention the script that i would write so as to get the current utc time, as seen in the variable a.

Comment: @whatf huh? You cannot create `Date` in UTC. Period. But you *can* create `Date` and then ask what time does it represent in UTC (as opposed to time in browser/OS time zone). What kind of code do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toUTCString` function if you need the string.

```
new Date().toUTCString()
```