# How to convert unix timestamp to JavaScript date object (consider time zone)

Tags: javascript, date

```
var date = new Date(1257397200000​);
document.write(date);
​
```

Ran the code above I got `Wed Nov 04 2009 23:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`

I am looking for a way to create date object based on different time zone, say for that time stamp I want to obtain date object like `Thursday, November 5th 2009, 00:00:00 (GMT -5)`.

Note that the dates are different according to above two time zones, **though they represent same point in time**. I am in CST, is that why the created object is generated using CST?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's most likely using your (local) time zone.  I don't know the library, but there should be a method somewhere to chose what timezone to report things in.  Please note that the timestamp should _not_ change.

Comment: Yes the timestamp wouldn't change. The answer for my question us great but you might also find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4322641/1413598) helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, these dates aren't different as they don't represent different point in time. The both represent `Thu, 05 Nov 2009 05:00:00 GMT`.

`Date` object in JavaScript is time-zone independent, it only represents point in time. The fact that `Date.toString()` includes time zone is very misleading, **there is no time-zone information in `Date`**. It is only a wrapper around milliseconds since epoch.

The time zone you see is based on OS/browser locale. **You cannot create `Date` object in different time-zone**. Consider using `getUTC*()` family of methods to get browser time-zone agnostic values.

BTW your example code prints:

```
Thu Nov 05 2009 06:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

on my computer - and this is still the same point in time.

## See also

- [Annoying javascript timezone adjustment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629286)

Comment: +1! Loving that you emphasized the `represents a point in time` point.

Comment: "You cannot create Date object in different time-zone." Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: So basically the answer is you don't need to care about user's timezone when converting timestamp into Date because it's done automatically, right?