# Parse ISOstring to date in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment js to deal with date and times in my project. When I'm trying to parse ISOstring to date format in moment js date and time are not coming properly.

This is my ISO string: `'2016-04-27T18:30:00.000Z'`, I'm doing like this

```
moment('2014-02-27T18:30:00.000Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

I'm getting like this when running the above code "**2014-02-28 00:00:00**"

How to get the correct time?

Comment: Which date format do you want? There is 4 dateTime formats: ISO Dates,
Long Dates,
Short Dates,
Full Format,

Comment: I need the output to be "2014-02-27 18:30:00"

Comment: Here is some information about moment js formats : http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange behavior formatting moment.js date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165182/strange-behavior-formatting-moment-js-date)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use another moment.js function, `parseZone`, since your date time format has time zone information.

```
moment.parseZone('2014-02-27T18:30:00.000Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
//moment.parseZone('2014-02-27T18:30:00.000Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: This is fine, but the `utc` function would be slightly more appropriate for this particular case.

Comment: I don't see why. If he wants to display the time as it's received, ignoring time zone info, I think the best option is use `parseZone()` and not `utc()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // April 27th 2016, 4:00:27 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Wednesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Apr 27th 16
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2016 escaped 2016
moment().format();                          // 2016-04-27T16:00:27+02:00
```

Hope it helps;)